# Android system does not notice that files has been deleted immediately

Tags: android

We use Nodejs mobile in our app. On startup it deletes app internal files, and then run `df` to get how much free space there is. Issue we noticed is that even that files are deleted without any errors, android system does not notice immediately that files have been deleted. So when we run `df` later, it returns not correct values and we end up thinking that there is less free space available. Last time i tested it took few minutes after deleting files untill `df` started returning correct values. Is there some android API that could be trigger to make this faster?

Comment: Where are the files located you delete (path) and how do you delete them (source code).

Comment: @Robert they are my apps files `'/data/user/0/com.my.ap/files/` and we do this in nodejs mobile code we use `fs.unlink`

Comment: That means the file is in the app-private directory and directly deleted by file-system operations. Therefore the delay should be located in the file-system. You have not mentioned the used phone, nor the Android version or what file-system is used 
- possible file-systems would be ext3/ext4, F2FS, YAFFS2. If you have the info you could ask someone with deep Linux knowledge if this is expected behavior on the used file-system and if you can speed-up the process as a simple user.

Comment: @Robert device is Chromecast With Google TV HD version. i think it runs android 12, not sure. Thanks for clues.